# Maven: Why is ${basedir} forbidden in <targetPath>?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

**Why `${basedir}` is not allowed in `<targetPath>`?**

When I add ${basedir} in pom.xml

```
<resource>
  <targetPath>${basedir}/target</targetPath>
</resource>
```

maven-eclipse-plugin [failed](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MECLIPSE-269):

```
$ mvn eclipse:eclipse
[ERROR] Cant canonicalize system path: {0}
```

Comment: The first question: Why are you trying to define it? Furthermore in relationship with Eclipse? Why not using m2e ? If you are using m2e than don't use eclipse:eclipse anymore.

Comment: @khmarbaise I define targetPath to copy configuration files needed by tests. It's not related to eclipse.

Comment: If you correctly locate them into **src/test/resources** the will be copied automatically to **target/test-classes**.

Comment: @khmarbaise it's an ant project and it doesn't conform to maven standards

Comment: So why does have maven tagged ? So it's no Maven question at all.

Comment: the project is built with maven to generate sonar reports

Comment: Sounds like a contradiction, cause on one side you say it's Ant on the other side you say it's Maven? If it's Maven you should follow the conventions otherwise you will get in trouble.

Comment: I meant: it was a former ant project that was on its way to be migrated to maven.